# How to convert column values to single row value in postgresql

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

Data

```
  id      cust_name

  1        walmart_ca
  2        ikea_mo
  2        ikea_ca
  2        ikea_in
  1        walmart_in
```

when i do

```
  select id,cust_name from test where id=2
```

Query returns below output

```
   id  cust_name

    2  ikea_mo
    2  ikea_ca
    2  ikea_in
```

How can i get or store the result as single column value as shown below

```
    id   cust_name

     2   {ikea_mo,ikea_ca,ikea_in}
```

Comment: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-aggregate-functions/postgresql-string_agg-function/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use `string_agg` function and here is an example for it

```
select  string_agg(field_1,',') from db.schema.table;
```

you should mention the separator in your case its  `,` so I am doing `string_agg(field_1,',')`